# Peaches, apricots and medlars: combination exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

We have to create a fruit composition with peaches, apricots and medlars. How many ways is it possible to create a basket of 20 pieces, under the condition that there are at least 6 peaches, at least 4 apricots and at least 2 medlars?

---

**My solution**: I named with $a =$ number of apricots; $n =$ number of medlars, and $p =$ number of peaches. The condition want that into a basket I must to have $12$ fruits: $6+4+2=12$. I have thinked that there are class 8 repetition combinations of the 3 '$abc$' objects i.e.. I know that for the combinations (without repetitions) there is a formula:

$$C_{n,k} = \frac{D_{n,k}}{P_k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = {n \choose k}$$
and with repetitions
$$C'_{n,k}=\binom {n+k-1}{n-1}=\binom {8+3-1}{8-1}=C'_{8,3}=\binom {10}{7}$$

The result is $45$ but $\binom {10}{7}=120$.

> My level of combination theory is low. I have never made combinations with repetition. I ask you if my reasoning is right, if there is another solution and what I did wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what went wrong.  You've mixed up the meanings of $n$ and $k$.  It should have been $\binom{8+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{10}{2}=45$

Comment: @JMoravitz I ask a different solution of the problem....after I have not understood the significance of your link, because I hae mixed up the meanings of $n$ and $k$. What is after the reason, with simple words?

Comment: As my link states, the number of arrangements is $\binom{\text{#Balls} + \text{#Bins}-1}{\text{#Bins}-1}$.  Here, the "bins" are like the available flavors of fruit and the "balls" are the actual pieces of fruit themselves.  Written in this formula without the use of "$n$" or "$k$" since it is easy to confuse which of the numbers should have been $n$ and which should have been $k$ and people can mix them up, like you have done here.

Comment: @JMoravitz How do I do to not mix the $n$ and $k$? I never I have done combinations wtih repetition. Can you expain me, please, with an answer to understand the tecnique? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem and as noticed by JMoravitz the problem is that you have mixed up the meanings of $n$ and $k$.

In this case we have

- $N=3$ is the number of "bins" (peaches, apricots and medlars)
- $K=8$ is the number of objects (fruits to select)

therefore

$$\binom {N+K-1}{N-1}=\binom {10}{2}=45$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a reason why I have mixed up the meanings of $n$ and $k$. Excuse me very much for my low level of the English language.

Comment: @Sebastiano In the stars and bars problem, if we take $N$ as the number of bins then the number of bars is $N-1$ and the number of stars is $K$.